# how can I rename a document with a unique ID in OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, office-2010

I'm creating a copy of an Office 2010 word document for some OpenXML automation. The below code blows up on File.Copy saying it doesn't like the path\name combination of the copiedPath variable

```
        string mainPath = @"Path\Name.docx";
        string copiedPath = @"Path\Name" +
        DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "-") +".docx";

        File.Copy(mainPath, copiedPath);
```

If I make the following change the code works fine:

```
string copiedPath = @"Path\Name_Test_.docx";
```

but since this is going to be used on the company intranet I'd like a better way to separate the different requests by users. Has anyone pulled off what I'm trying to do or can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the ':' char between the hours and minutes is the problem in your target path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to have a `:` in a file name, so you will have to replace that charactor as well.